# DROPPING FOREIGN KEY BY CONSTNAME

Tags: sql, database, db2

I want to drop a foreign key from a table but I do not know its identifier.

I get the identifier from the SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE table.

After that I try to use that identifier to drop the FK.

Getting identifier

```
SELECT keycoluse.CONSTNAME FROM SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE keycoluse WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'USER1' AND TABNAME = 'TABLE1' AND COLNAME = 'ID_TABLE'
```

result = ID000000001

Dropping FK

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
DROP FOREIGN KEY (SELECT keycoluse.CONSTNAME FROM SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE keycoluse WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'USER1' AND TABNAME = 'TABLE1' AND COLNAME = 'ID_TABLE');
```

this throw error:  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]

But if I use the identifier I got before in this way, it works:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
DROP FOREIGN KEY ID000000001;
```

In this way, it does not work:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
DROP FOREIGN KEY 'ID000000001';
```

When I execute the SELECT to get the id, it gets a varchar 'ID000000001' and that gives the error.

¿Is there a way to cast the result of the SELECT into the same type that we have in this command?

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
DROP FOREIGN KEY ID000000001;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a variable (returned by a subselect) or a literal where an identifier is required.

What you *can* do is generate a script from the query you have, although I cannot imagine why you would want to use such a complex approach to drop a single constraint:

```
SELECT 
  'ALTER TABLE', 'TABLE1',
  'DROP FOREIGN KEY', keycoluse.CONSTNAME 
FROM 
  SYSCAT.KEYCOLUSE keycoluse 
WHERE 
  TABSCHEMA = 'USER1' AND TABNAME = 'TABLE1' AND COLNAME = 'ID_TABLE'
```

The query will return a correct `ALTER` statement. You can copy/paste it into your favourite client software or write results to a text file and execute it, for example, with

```
db2 -f mydropscript.sql
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that using these kinds of scripts are generally the proper approach, when making larger changes; one shouldn't be too dissuaded from using them.